# Confusion about constant initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

In [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization) it gives the syntax of **constant initialization**:

```
static T & ref = constexpr; 
static T object = constexpr;
```

Here's my two questions:

### Q1

How could a lvalue reference `T &` without `const` be bound to a `constexptr`,which is constant and unmodifiable ?

I try to provide some example but failed:

```
 static int& ref = 6; //error, need a `const`
 constexpr int a = 6; static int& ref = a; //error, need a `const`
```

### Q2

Is it a necessity for the object of constant initialization to be `const`/`static` ?In [the standard](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#def:constant_initialization) it says:

> Constant initialization is performed **if a variable or temporary object with static or thread storage duration** is initialized by a constant initializer for the entity.

Here the standard does not specify the obj to be `const-qualified`/`static-qualified`.

Comment: A static must be initialized with a `constexpr` statement, but that doesn't mean the static itself must be `constexpr`.  This works: `static int a=6; 
static int& ref=a;`  **EDIT:** Though based on the wording I think this no longer qualifies as constant initialization.

Comment: It seems your editing asked another question. Maybe it is better to ask a new question rather than editing.

Comment: @xskxzr But I've received answers for both questions.And I edited it again to make it more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The confusion is due to the naming: the term *constant* in *constant initialization* [[basic.start.static]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static#2) and *constant expression* [[expr.const]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const) means **evaluable at compile time without heroic efforts(1) of the compiler**. This differs from the concept of a constant object which means that the value of the object will not changed once defined.

To illustrate the limit of evaluation at compile time let's look at the assembly of this code:

```
//case 0
int i0 = 5;
int j0 = i0;//no compil-time initialized
//case 1
const int i1=5; 
int j1=i1; //compil-time initialized
//case 2
extern const int i2=5; 
int j2=i2; //compile-time initialized
//case 3
extern const int i3; 
int j3=i3; //no compil-time initialization
//case 4
extern const int i4; 
int j4=i4; //no compil-time initialization
const int i4=5;
```

Generated assembly by gcc 7.3:

```
_GLOBAL__sub_I_example.cpp: # @_GLOBAL__sub_I_example.cpp
  mov eax, dword ptr [rip + i0]
  mov dword ptr [rip + j0], eax
  mov eax, dword ptr [rip + i3]
  mov dword ptr [rip + j3], eax
  mov dword ptr [rip + j4], 5
  ret
```

What is happening for:

- case 0, j0 is not initialized at compil-time because i0 is not a constant.[[expr.constant]/2.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#2.7)
- case 1 and 2, are compil-time initialized because they fit to an exception of the previous rule [[expr.constant]/2.7.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#2.7.1).
- case 3 and case4, j3 and j4 are not initialized at compil-time because they do not fit to this last rule exception because they have not a preceding initialization, (at least it could be solved at link time, but this would be an heroic effort or dependent of the implementation quality)

---

(1) the principle is that the language shall not be too complex to compile. I just recycled the wording of the standard for *template argument deduction* where the term *heroic effort* appears litteraly. The same principle is applied to define what is a constant expression.

Comment: what about `static a=1;static b=a`.Is `b` evaluatable at compiled time?

Comment: @bigxiao According to the standard `a` is not a constant expression, nevertheless gcc initialize it at compil-time because of the "as-if" rule. Nevertheless you can try to instantiate a template with a, the compilation will fail: `std::integral_constant<int,a>`.

Comment: You said that "constant expression means evaluable at compile time ",I think it doesn't cover some special situations.For exmaple,`a`,`b` are all evaluable at compile time,but `b` is not **constant initization**,and `a` is not **constant expression**   (`a` is **constant initialization** )

Comment: @bigxiao, gcc do not use of the as-if rule for non static case, because it do not know if the variable is going to be changed in an other translation unit, consider this case: `//file1.cpp;  int f(); int i=5; int k=f(); int j=i;` and `file2.cpp;  extern int i; int f(){ return ++i;}`

Comment: @bigxiao I have written "evaluable at compile time without heroic efforts of the compiler". I remove the parenthesis around heroic efforts. What is an heroic effort is deductible from [expr.constant]. The goal of the example I show was precisely to show you that even if *you* are able evaluate at compile time the value of an expression, the compiler is allowed not to do it, and this is defined in [expr.constant]

Answer (score 6):

What that is trying to say is that

```
static int a;
static int & ref = a;
static_assert(&a == &ref, "");
```

is okay. The initialisation is a form of constant initialisation because `a` is a constant expression when evaluated as an lvalue (but only as an lvalue!), and as a result of that, `&a == &ref` is a constant expression which evaluates to `true`.

Compare this to

```
void f() {
  int a;
  static int & ref = a;
  static_assert(&a == &ref, "");
}
```

This is invalid. Although the initialisation of `ref` is technically valid, it becomes a dangling reference as soon as the function returns. The next time the function is entered, a new `int a` object is created. Because of that, `&a == &ref` is not guaranteed to evaluate to `true`. It is not a constant expression, and would have undefined behaviour if evaluated.

Comment: Is there a necessity for the object of constant initialization to be `const`?

Comment: @bigxiao No. Just plain `static int i = 1;` is also constant initialisation.

Comment: It's constant init as long as both the initializer and the variable are of **static duration** (or could be evaluated at compile time) .Am I right?

Comment: @bigxiao I'm not sure what you mean by that. In `static int i = 1;`, the initialiser `1` is a prvalue, so doesn't have static storage duration. In `static int i; static int j = i;`, the initialiser `i` has static storage duration but this still isn't constant initialisation.

Comment: I have edited and add " (or could be evaluated at compile time) ",so `1` could satisty the condition.

Comment: @bigxiao I have edited my comment too to address that.

Comment: Oh.I seems to understand what is **constant init**,that is,something be initialized by a **constant expression**.If that's true,the cppref is misleading,because it has nothing to do with `static` at all.

Comment: @bigxiao It does: `void f() { int i = 1; }` is not constant initialisation. `void g() { static int i = 1; }` is constant initialisation. But at file scope, `static int a = 1; int b = 1;` are both constant initialisation. It's not about the keyword `static` directly, it's about having static storage duration.

Comment: OK,so there are two requirements for **constant init**: 1. the variable has **static duration**, 2. the `rhs` is constant expression.

Answer (score 3):

"constant initialization" means *the initializer* is a constant expression. Neither the expression nor the variable need to be const-qualified.

`int x = 6;` at file scope is constant initialization.

Reference: C++17 [basic.start.static]/2:

> *Constant initialization* is performed if a variable or temporary object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constant initializer for the entity.

Comment: The word `constant`,which seems like `const-qualified`, is misleading.Does the term `constant` actually means **static duration**?

Comment: It's constant init as long as both the initializer and the variable are of **static duration**.Am I right?

Comment: @bigxiao yes, or thread. And the initializer must be a constant expression

Comment: Can I say that every "constant initialization" is "compile-time initialization"?

Comment: @mada the standard doesn't really distinguish compile-time and run-time. Constant initialization is performed before any dynamic initialization though.

Answer (score 1):

In the page you reference you can read

> Sets the initial values of the static constants

I point your attention over **constants**

So `T` must be a constant type.

So `int const` is OK; `constexpr int` is OK because `constexpr` imply `const`; `int` without `const` (or without `constexpr` that imply `const`) is wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't say that `int` without `const` is *wrong*, just that it would use some other form of initialization that isn't "constant initialization".

Comment: @0x5453 - Not sure to understand what you mean, anyway... you're right: a `static` variable not necessarily is a constant one; so `static int a=6; static int& ref=a;` is OK; but the OP ask for a [precise page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization) in cppreference that is about initialization of "static constants". So `static int a=6;` and `static int& ref=a;` doesn't match that page.

Comment: [Constant initialization](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#def:constant_initialization) is a terminology defined in the standard. I guess the description in cppreference is inaccurate.

Comment: But the standard does not specify the obj to be `constant`,please see my edited question.